# How can I made constructor point In ECC.? (plz help)

Tags: algorithm, security

I am a student who is study about ECC algorithm.

By Learning ECC, I have a question
**how can I calculate constructor point which is satisfied y^2 = x^3 + ax + b**

I try to use random point which is not satisfied that, but then the result of Q( = xG) can be **n/0**

1 How can I calculate constructor point?
1' If you can, plz give me a source

2 how can I calculate (a, 0)+(a, 0) in Elliptic-curve

I really want to know the answer. plz help me

Comment: You might have more luck when you try here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can chose x at random, then calculate x^3 + ax + b and if this is a square in the field (otherwise choose another x) finally y by taking the modular square root, for example using Tonelli-Shanks algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm

`(a, 0)+(a, 0)` can be calculated with the double formula (provided (a,0) is a point on the curve). The result is the point at infinity O (i.e. the neutral element of the group). I am ignoring singular curves here.